# Use GLSL-Unit to compile fragment shader

Tags: glsl, webgl

I want to use [GLSL-Unit](http://code.google.com/p/glsl-unit/wiki/UsingTheCompiler) to just minify a fragment shader. But if I do run this command:

```
sunbox$ glsl-compiler --input=/Users/sunbox/Sites/bessa-app/xyz.fshader
```

I'm getting these error messages:

```
/usr/local/bin/glsl-compiler: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `b'
/usr/local/bin/glsl-compiler: line 1: `var COMPILED=true,goog=goog||{};goog.global=this;goog.DEBUG=true;goog.LOCALE="en";goog.provide=function(b){if(!COMPILED){if(goog.isProvided_(b))throw Error('Namespace "'+b+'" already declared.');delete goog.implicitNamespaces_[b];for(var f=b;f=f.substring(0,f.lastIndexOf("."));){if(goog.getObjectByName(f))break;goog.implicitNamespaces_[f]=true}}goog.exportPath_(b)};'
```

So, how do I simply minify a fragment shader?

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it working. :D

For everyone who's interested, you need this file:
http://code.google.com/p/glsl-unit/source/browse/bin/template_glsl_compiler.js

... and [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) installed. Then add a simple comment in your shader file:

```
//! FRAGMENT

precision lowp float;
uniform sampler2D image;
varying vec2 src_position;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(image, src_position);
}
```

... and annoyingly you have to use the .glsl file extension! :(
Now you can run this command:

```
sunbox$ node /Volumes/template_glsl_compiler.js  --input=/Volumes/test.glsl --variable_renaming=INTERNAL --output=/Volumes/test.fshader.min
```

And that's it. Compiled output will be:

```
//! VERTEX

//! FRAGMENT
precision lowp float;uniform sampler2D image;varying vec2 a;void main(){gl_FragColor=texture2D(image,a);}
```

Really nice! :)

Comment: Why is using `.glsl` annoying? Granted GLSL has no official file extension (considering OpenGL does not use files), but `.glsl` is probably the closest thing it has. Most text editors, including vim, will highlight `.glsl` files but not `.fshader` or `.vshader` or `.gshader` or `.tshader`. Long ago, I adopted a policy of `_vs.glsl` for vtx shaders, `_fs.glsl` for fragment, `_gs.glsl` for geometry, `_tes.glsl` for tess. eval., `_tcs.glsl` for tess. control. This way you can still quickly identify which shader is for which stage, and benefit from syntax highlighting as well.

Comment: It is annoying, because there's no official file extension. Why do they force me to use `.glsl`? I'm using `.fshader` and `.vshader` for all my shaders, because there's no official file extension. Now I have to chage this to `_fs.glsl` and `_vs.glsl`. Just changing an unsupported file extension to another unsupported file extension is annoying to me.